# How can I install GTK on MacOS (Big sur)?

Tags: macos

I have tried running this on my MacBook:

```
brew install gtk+3
```

but the following appears:

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but... Did you run the commands the error message tells you to run?

Comment: @NicholasRees no, sorry. the truth is that I am not very familiar with the terminal and I would prefer someone who knows to receive some help, I would not want to do something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say... it says run the commands  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and  chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig . Try running them and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you were right I only had to run one of the commands. sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error's you got run: **sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig**

change the **whoami** to your user name,

Then run: **chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig**

Comment: It may be helpful to explain what those commands does since the OP is not familiar with unix commands.

Comment: whoami - print the user named, chmod is used to change the access mode of a file.
The name is an abbreviation of change mode, and u+w... I guess 'u' = the person who created the file and 'w' = ability to change the content of the file